# How to configure Open vSwitch bridge to make all ports trunked?

Tags: networking, virtualization, xen, vlan

I am trying to configure open vSwitch on a XenServer install to trunk all ports with VLANs. How would I make it so that whenever a new VM is added the port that is connected to it is automatically trunked with the VLANs I need. Rather than have to manually make them a trunk port each time I start the VM up.